# Can't debug in Edge using Aurelia CLI build

Tags: microsoft-edge, aurelia

I'm using ASP.NET Core with an Aurelia CLI build (TypeScript, SASS).

I've noticed that I can't debug my TypeScript files in Edge at all - the browser says it is unable to find the source maps, even though the locations are correct and the source maps exist. I can't see any of my src files in the source file browser.

There is no issue with Chrome or Firefox, they just work.

I tested a vanilla HTML / TypeScript project which is fine in Edge for debugging, so it must be something to do with the way the files are packaged in the Aurelia build system.

The specific error I get is along the lines of:

"Could not locate file:///XXXX specified in source map http://localhost:16377/scripts/app-bundle.js.map"

Is this a known issue? Is there any fix for it?

Comment: I am running Sass and Edge gives the error while Chrome is fine and is able to use and find the maps.

Answer (score 1):

This is definitely an issue with the CLI and how it is producing sourcemaps. It looks like HTML files are having their path in the sourcemap file written as the full drive path on the machine, while the content of the file actually isn't being written out at all.

I've created an issue on our CLI repo: https://github.com/aurelia/cli/issues/409

Comment: Yes I see the full file path on my local drive in the error dialog too.

Comment: I've created a pull request that fixes this problem. It should get pushed out in the next release of the CLI in the next day or two: https://github.com/aurelia/cli/pull/410

Comment: @Sam Have you verified this was the fix needed? Please mark this as this as answered. Thanks!